# Tangent line of instantaneous rate of change

Tags: calculus

I am currently experiencing some problems doing my review , for my quiz tomorrow! Basically, we are learning about instantaneous rate of change , which is section 2.2 (quiz on 2.1-2.2) . And then while I was going through the notes the last parts I had trouble on! Basically, these were the

### Picture

***Above***:
[image]

***Below***:
[image]

### Words

> b. Draw the ***tangent line*** at the data point for the time *1:17pm*.

Well as you can see I have drawn the tangent line on the Picture above labeled `Above` .

But my problems are on when it says

**Tangent Line at Point P** . I don't understand what I am suppose to do there :/ . Also, you can see I didn't fill out the third Blank:

> So the **Instantaneous rate of change** at Point P is the _________________ of the **tangent line** at point P.

If anyone can help me on these 2 problems , that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a bunch for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read the first question, but I think the second one is a very important concept to get.  The derivative is the slope of the tangent line.  A derivative at a point is the slope of the tangent line at that point.  Hopefully, this diagram will make this clearer to you.
http://www.math.umn.edu/~arnold/calculus/differential/differential-g.html

Comment: yea i latter got the second one , as the missing letter was the word slope .. The first one says "Tangent Line at Point P ." , as i said in the words section.. Any hints on that?

Comment: the word you are looking for is slope

Comment: Since the derivative evaluated at a point is the Instantaneous rate of change at that point

Comment: Yes thats the second question. You know the answer for first one? Thats the reallllyy troublinng one!! :(